# Generic type class for EF Core join results

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Trying to come up with a dynamically typed class for storing results from querying my EF Core dbcontext. What I'm trying to avoid is creating a new class for every join combination I might need.
For example, I have these 2 entities that I want to join in a query:

```cs
List<Person> People = new List<Person>(){ new Person(){ Id = 1, Name = "John Doe"}};
List<Address> Addresses = new List<Address>(){ new Address(){ Id = 1, City = "Anonland"}};
```

What I have tried is:

a) Creating a generic type class that just contains one each of the provided type params

```cs
public class QueryResult<T1, T2> {
        public T1 t1;
        public T2 t2;

        public QueryResult(T1 t1, T2 t2) {
            this.t1 = t1;
            this.t2 = t2;
        }
    }
```

then

```cs
List<QueryResult<Person, Address> res = 
            People.Join(
                Addresses,
                p => p.Id,
                a => a.Id,
                (p,a) => new QueryResult<Person, Address>(p, a))
            .ToList();

foreach (var x in res){
    Console.WriteLine($"{x.t1.Name} - {x.t2.City}");
}
```

I can live with this, but I would prefer to have more descriptive var names than t1 / t2, which I don't think I can accomplish using this method.

and b) using an implementation of `Dictionary<string,object>`:

```cs
public class QueryResult<T1, T2> : Dictionary<string, object> {
    public QueryResult(T1 a, T2 b){
        this.Add(typeof(T1).ToString(), a);
        this.Add(typeof(T2).ToString(), b);        
    }
}
```

then

```cs
List<QueryResult<Person, Address> res = 
            People.Join(
                Addresses,
                p => p.Id,
                a => a.Id,
                (p,a) => new QueryResult<Person, Address>(p, a))
            .ToList();

foreach (var x in res){
            Console.WriteLine(((Person)x["Person"]).Name + " - " + ((Address)x["Address"]).City);
        }
```

This also *works* and is more descriptive, but then accessing and casting the objects is long-winded and redundant.

Is there some sort of middle ground here that I'm missing? Or maybe just going about this entirely the wrong way?

Comment: Can't you use a tuple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use [value tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) available since C# 7 which allow to specify [field names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-field-names)?

```
List<(Person Person, Address Address)> res = 
            People.Join(
                Addresses,
                p => p.Id,
                a => a.Id,
                (p,a) => (p, a))
            .ToList();
```

Or using `var`:

```
var res = People.Join(
                Addresses,
                p => p.Id,
                a => a.Id,
                (p,a) => (Person: p, Address: a))
            .ToList();
 
foreach (var x in res){
        Console.WriteLine(x.Person.Name + " - " + x.Address.City);
    }
```

Comment: Absolutely can do that, thanks! Wasn't aware of this and apparently didn't hit the sweet spot with Google search terms. Figured I was over complicating this.

Comment: "Why not just use..." Because they are not supported in expression trees? @JasonTressler It's not EF Core problem, they can't support something not supported by C# compiler.

Comment: @JasonTressler Sorry, missed the part about using it for EF for some reason got focused on the code =) . If you don't need to return the result as is from your method - you can use anonymous types  changing `(p,a) => (Person: p, Address: a)` to `(p,a) => new {Person = p, Address = a}`.

Comment: Unfortunately I do need to return this since it's wrapped in a method in my DAL (this is a Blazor server app). The answer I came up with below based on yours is workable though. 

@IvanStoev Edited my answer. You're right, it's a compiler issue, not EF Core

Answer (score 0):

So for future reference, 'tuple literals' are not supported in expression trees, so I was getting compiler errors with this. What I ended up having to do is instantiate a tuple explicitly

```cs
List<Tuple<Person, Address>> res = 
            People.Join(
                Addresses,
                p => p.Id,
                a => a.Id,
                (p,a) => new Tuple<Person, Address>(p, a))
            .ToList();

foreach (var x in res){
    // x.Item1.Name, etc
}
```

which still introduces the less descriptive Item1...ItemN, but at least avoids creating a custom class.